# Can I modify a python version inside venv without affecting that version outside of venv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtual, python-venv

I want to modify some python39 packages inside venv, will this affect the python39 outside the venv?

Comment: No packages outside of the virtual environment will be affected. That's the point of having a virtual environment, so that you can work in a separate "environment" with particular packages and their versions.

Comment: That is literally one of the reasons why you use venv. And as everyone commented, Yes. You can modify it.

Comment: Just be sure, if you are using `pip` that you have activated your virtual environment first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? Literally the first paragraph explains: "Each virtual environment has its own Python binary (which matches the version of the binary that was used to create this environment) and can have its own independent set of installed Python packages in its site directories."

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, those are different environments and won't affect on each other.